# Include source files of package in .NET Core MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

In a project.json based project I was able to reference (source) files in a nuget package quite easily. I just added the following to project.json, and I could reference the classes in my code. Even with code-completion.

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.Extensions.DotnetToolDispatcher.Sources": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

Now I tried to migrate to the MSBuild based tooling (with tooling version 1.0.0-rc4-004771), but I can't get the same to work in the csproj file.

I've added the following reference to the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DotnetToolDispatcher.Sources" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But after adding the reference, the resources (source files) in the package are still not found. For example, in the project.json project I could simply call the following method, which is present in the package, `Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.DotnetToolDispatcher.IsDispatcher()`, but the class (or method, etc) is not recognized in my .csproj project.

I think I might have to explicitly add a `<Compile Include="x" />` statement, but what do I write in the include? How do I reference the package above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.0.0 version of this particular package does not support MSBuild. It uses a folder layout that only worked in project.json. MSBuild requires that packages containing C# files use the "contentFiles" feature instead.

See the following links for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#including-content-files

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/236

Comment: Thanks! I read about it, but (incorrectly) thought it was a compile-time thing. Kind of sucks that existing packages will have to be updated so they work again with MSBuild.